# reducing if statements in C for efficiency

Tags: c, if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements, reduce

I am trying to make my code more efficient by reducing the number of conditional statements as I am going to write the code in assembly in the future. Do you guys see any way to reduce the statements to be more efficient?

```
if (j==18)
{
    store=12;
}
else if(j==30)
{
    store=10;
}
else if(j==42)
{
    store=8;
}
else if(j==54)
{
    store=6;
}
else if(j==66)
{
    store=4;
}
else if(j==78)
{
    store=2;
}
else if(j==92)
{
    store=2;
}
else if(j==106)
{
    store=4;
}
else if(j==120)
{
    store=6;
}
else if(j==134)
{
    store=8;
}
else if(j==148)
{
    store=10;
}
else if(j==162)
{
    store=12;
}
else store=1;
```

Comment: why ifs, why don't you calculate it? Seems to me as single if is enough, then divide by 12 or 14, round as desired, and add/subtract to get final value. What is `j` and `store`, integers? How many bits? What should happen for other values you don't show (I see *now* `store=1;` at end, is that hard requirement?)

Comment: Well, in order to reduce the number of if statements, you must have a clear pattern, and then you can use arithmetic operations.

Comment: For pity's sake, choose a consistent indentation scheme for the code.  It's all over the place in the example.  How often will you be exercising this code?  How often will the list of mapped values change?  What is  the range of the input values?  Are the outputs strictly limited to 1..12?  All your stores have two codes that map to them except store 1.  Is that coincidental?

Comment: basically, this block of code runs in a version of insertion sort  that is going through a diamond so I have to skip certain indices so the store variable is being used within a while loop to determine the decrement in the insertion sort

Comment: Too much depends on the actual data for there to be a correct answer in all cases. For this specific data, I would use a calculated lookup table.

Comment: If it's decrement in insertion sort, then maybe you can deduct it from the phase you are in too. BTW, you didn't answer my questions, which makes difficult to post good answer.

Comment: int j is the value preceding the for loop counter for insertion sort. store is an interger as well that holds the decrementing value within the while loop. store=1 is a hard requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it would definitely be faster (and more compact) to use a switch statement instead of a series of if statements. Most languages can optimize a switch statement much better than a series of ifs. Your code would look something like this in switch statement form:

```
switch(j) {
    case 18:
        store = 12;
        break;
    case 30:
        store = 10;
        break;
    // and so on
    default:
        store = 1;
}
```

Of course, this won't be as fast as a version of your code without conditionals (probably). If you could come up with a mathematical formula to calculate the value of `store` in terms of `j`, that would (probably) be a lot faster.

Comment: how would I implement the final else statement with this method so that store=1? Sorry, I am pretty new to programming and this is only my second month of programming so sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: This will probably compile to either a jump table (if the `j` values aren't too sparse) or a chain of compare/branch instructions.  Making a data lookup table is potentially much better, because AFAIK compilers don't typically make that optimization.

Comment: Yea, you're probably right that a data lookup table would be the fastest option. Unfortunately, I didn't think of it while writing the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (j < 18 || 162 < j) {
    store = 1;
} else if (j < 90) {
    int mod12 = (j-6) % 12;
    // ((j-6)/12) -> 18=>1, .. 78=>6  (/6 used to get *2)
    store = (mod12) ? 1 : 14 - ((j-6) / 6);
} else {
    int mod14 = (j-8) % 14;
    // ((j-8)/14) -> 92=>6, ... 162=>11 (/7 used to get *2)
    store = (mod14) ? 1 : ((j-8) / 7) - 10;
}
```

Which can be implemented straightforwardly enough by manual assembler, although modern C++ compiler will do better than ordinary human, [for example gcc 7.3 produces something a bit better](https://godbolt.org/g/kqGB6T) than I had originally on my mind (and something I wouldn't want to write by hand).

---

Actually the gcc can be [hand-holded a bit to understand that formula better](https://godbolt.org/g/GTthJ9).

Modified source:

```
if (j < 18 || 162 < j) {
    store = 1;
} else if (j < 90) {
    int mod12 = (j-6) % 12;
    // ((j-6)/12) -> 18=>1, .. 78=>6
    store = (mod12) ? 1 : 14 - 2*((j-6) / 12);
} else {
    int mod14 = (j-8) % 14;
    // ((j-8)/14) -> 92=>6, ... 162=>11
    store = (mod14) ? 1 : 2*((j-8) / 14) - 10;
}
```

And for completeness, here is `switch` version (didn't benchmark it, but should be quite slower than the code above): https://godbolt.org/g/ELNCYD

Looks like the gcc was unable to figure it out and does use many "ifs" for that one.

---

**NEW**: so after checking all those compilers/and comments, this looks to be most [performance] optimal x86_64 solution (subroutine taking "j" in `edi` and returning "store" in `rax`) (NASM syntax):

```lisp
; input: edi = j, output: rax = store
storeByJ:
    sub     edi, 18
    cmp     edi, (162-18)
    ja      .JoutOfRange    ; j < 18 || 162 < j -> return 1
    ; rdi = 0 .. 162-18 = 144
    movzx   eax, byte [rel .JtoStoreLUT + rdi]
    ret
.JoutOfRange:
    mov     eax,1
    ret

.JtoStoreLUT:
    ;        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F
    db      12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         ; 18->12
    db      10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         ; 30->10
    db       8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         ; 42->8
    db       6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         ; 54->6
    db       4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         ; 66->4
    db       2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ; 78->2
    db       2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ; 92->2
    db       4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ;106->4
    db       6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ;120->6
    db       8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ;134->8
    db      10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1   ;148->10
    db      12                                          ;162->12
```

If you would have much larger range (more values) being still +12 and after some point +14 differentiated, the formula may get better (by saving the cache memory from the too-big LUT (Look-Up-Table)), but at this moment this code is about 170B long even with the LUT data, so it will very likely fit even with the whole loop using it.

---

EDIT: one more variant, with half-sized LUT, but using `ror` to filter out odd values by single jump in the range test (I'm not sure about performance, but as with any other code-efficient questions, profiling is absolutely essential, above all the theoretical reasoning, if you can't confirm your theory in benchmark, fix your benchmark (lot more likely), or find out surprising intricacies of the CPU internals and how you misunderstood something... (but this is still likely enough to happen often)).. and the range branch is eliminated by using `cmovCC` (total 97B):

```lisp
; input: edi = j, output: eax = store
storeByJ:
    mov     eax, 1
    sub     edi, 18
    ror     edi, 1          ; /2 but keeps "odd" bit in the edi
                            ; to make it fail range check on next line
    cmp     edi, (162-18)/2
    cmova   edi, eax        ; j < 18 || 162 < j || j&1 -> return 1 (from LUT[1])
    ; rdi = 0 .. (162-18)/2 = 72  # rdi = (j-18)/2
    movzx   eax, byte [rel .JtoStoreLUT + rdi]
    ret

.JtoStoreLUT:
    ;        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
    db      12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1       ;  18->12
    db      10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1       ;  30->10
    db       8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1       ;  42->8
    db       6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1       ;  54->6
    db       4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1       ;  66->4
    db       2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ;  78->2
    db       2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ;  92->2
    db       4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ; 106->2
    db       6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ; 120->2
    db       8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ; 134->2
    db      10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1    ; 148->2
    db      12                      ; 162->2
```

Comment: Other compilers use a jump table for the switch, so it's pretty bad (https://godbolt.org/g/nx9XK2).  *far* worse than a `movzx` byte LUT with `j>>1` as an index.  I'd definitely consider a LUT here, after branching on `j` being odd or out-of-range.  I should report this as a missed-optimization I guess.

Comment: It looks like gcc is still using boilerplate signed-division code even after the range-check proves that `j-6` and `j-8` are non-negative :(  Using `unsigned ju = j` in the right places avoids that.  https://godbolt.org/g/pBLp44.  If this is inside a hot loop, though, a byte LUT is still significantly better.  It only takes a couple cache lines.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc uhm.. I just read the original values in `if`s and did some quick math to see how they differ? Also I would expect the deeper meaning in the sort algorithm to be probably solvable by simpler formula, this looks "fixed" in wrong way, but OP didn't post that, so that's just speculation.

Comment: @PeterCordes one thing I find weird about those LUTs produced: why jumps? Why doesn't it just load the new `store` value from the switch table and continue with universal `ret store;`? Feels like there's always some shortcoming with each compiler. I can see the value-instead-of-jump is just rare case optimization for this particular `case` style, but I would expect it to happen often-enough in real production to be worth of it.

Comment: Yeah, I think fixing this missed-optimization could benefit a significant amount of code (especially if compiling with retpolines for indirect branches as Spectre mitigation).  And I'm a bit surprised no compiler implemented it.

Comment: @PeterCordes so I wrote the x86_64 variant with byte LUT, feel free to reuse in case you would dare to contact compiler vendors, I don't have enough enthusiasm for that (I'm sort of happy there are still places where hand assembly pay off ;) ). BTW, is it worth to `shr edi,1` + `jc` to get half LUT size?

Comment: Suggestion: index the LUT with `j>>1` so it takes 1.125 cache lines instead of 2.25.  If it's in a large enough and hot enough loop, it could be worth skipping that one instruction, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes how about `rorx edi,1`? (so the `cmp+ja` will catch also odd values) .. is it better than cmp+ja+shr+jc?

Comment: @Ped7g: oh right, forgot about having to test for odd and return the default.  Yeah very nice idea with `ror`.  And BTW, you could make it branchless by using a cmov with an index that selects the default.  Maybe worth doing if `ror` or `rorx` would mean the branch doesn't predict perfectly anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to use an array 162 char or even less if those are all the j you must deal with.
It sounds as a memory waste but consider all those instruction saved, they occupy memory too. M2c

Comment: All of the `j` values are even, so you could just right-shift it if it's in-range and even.  e.g. `if (j & 1 || j<min || j>max ) store = 1; else store = LUT[ j>>1 ];`  Also, you can subtract  the min value so the first useful table entry is at `[0]`.  The compiler will want to `sub reg, 10` anyway as part of compiling the range check.

Comment: That's what I had in mind too while writing "162 char or even less".